# Creating String from list

Tags: tcl

I have a string like below:

```
 (A-B,C&D-E,F,G&H-I,J,K);
```

In the above string i used split command with "&" and got following elements :

```
 (A-B,C); (D-E,F,G) ;(H-I,J,K);
```

In the above element added Z in second element :

```
 (A-B,C); (D-E,F,G,Z); (H-I,J,K);
```

Now want to reconstruct string to original with z added for example :

```
 (A-B,C&D-E,F,G,Z&H-I,J,K);
```

Kindly share your suggestions thank you.

Comment: Is the original string `A-B,C&D-E,F,G&H-I,J,K` or does it have the parentheses and semicolon too? **Be exact.** It affects the exact answer you get.

Answer (score 1):

```
set s "(A-B,C&D-E,F,G&H-I,J,K);"
set l [split $s "&"]
lset l 1 "[lindex $l 1],Z"
set new [join $l &]
puts $new
```

```
(A-B,C&D-E,F,G,Z&H-I,J,K);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's suppose you have the three elements in a list

```tcl
puts $elements
{(A-B,C);} {(D-E,F,G,Z);} {(H-I,J,K);}
```

First of all, let's remove `(` and `);` from each element

```tcl
set trimmed [list]

foreach e $elements {
    lappend trimmed [string trim $e "();"]
}
```

Now whe have a new list:

```tcl
puts $trimmed
A-B,C D-E,F,G,Z H-I,J,K
```

Finally, let's `join` the list using the `&` character, and add again `(` in front of the resulting string and `);` at the end:

```tcl
set final ([join $trimmed &])\;
puts $final
(A-B,C&D-E,F,G,Z&H-I,J,K);
```

This should be all.